# how to create a view in oracle based on dual?

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to create this view in oracle but it doesn't work

```
create view view_E as
SELECT 'value 1' col from dual  UNION  
SELECT 'value 2'  from dual UNION   
SELECT 'value 3'  from dual UNION  
SELECT 'value 4'  from dual
```

the select works fine and I want to create a view based on it.
the equivalent of this code works on SQL server is there a rule that says you can't create a view based on select from dual thanks.

Comment: This should work fine. What error you are getting while creating it ?

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a standard Oracle error. Post the error. And do not tag `plsql`, as it is not related to `plsql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there're no problems in your code
see log of the scipt in SQLPlus

```
Connected to Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 
Connected as user1

SQL> 
SQL> create or replace view view_E as
  2  SELECT 'value 1' col from dual  UNION
  3  SELECT 'value 2'  from dual UNION
  4  SELECT 'value 3'  from dual UNION
  5  SELECT 'value 4'  from dual;

View created
SQL> /

View created
SQL> select * from view_E
  2  /

COL
-------
value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4

SQL>
```

Comment: it's odd i'm working with toad for oracle i tried this code a multiple of times and it always gives me this error
[Error] Execution (36: 30): ORA-00604: une erreur s'est produite au niveau SQL récursif 1
ORA-01801: format date trop grand par rapport à la mémoire tampon interne
ORA-06512: à ligne 2

Comment: @essanousy It is impossible to get those  two ORA errors with the code you have posted. Either you are obfuscating the code, or the error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: I'm thinking about Unicode symbols. Can your confirm that your code is exactly as you provided and has no unicode symbols?